# Gulp (pump, run-sequence) "task completion callback called too many times"

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm trying to use `gulp-pump` and `gulp-run-sequence`, but am hitting an error about `task completion callback called too many times`.

Below is my Gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var pump = require('pump');

var pumpCb = function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ', err.toString());
    }
};

// Local

gulp.task('local-sass', function (pumpCb) {
    return pump([
            gulp.src('public/assets/src/sass/**/*.scss'),
            sass(),
            autoprefixer(),
            gulp.dest('public/assets/dist/css/')
        ],
        pumpCb
    );
});

gulp.task('local-js', function (pumpCb) {
    return pump([
            gulp.src('public/assets/src/js/**/*.js'),
            uglify(),
            gulp.dest('public/assets/dist/js/')
        ],
        pumpCb
    );
});

// Production

gulp.task('prod-sass', function (pumpCb) {
    return pump([
            gulp.src('public/assets/src/sass/**/*.scss'),
            sass({outputStyle:'compact'}),
            autoprefixer(),
            gulp.dest('public/assets/dist/css/')
        ],
        pumpCb
    );
});

gulp.task('prod-css', function (pumpCb) {
    return pump([
            gulp.src(['./public/assets/dist/css/**/*.css','!./public/assets/dist/css/**/*.min*']),
            cleanCSS(),
            rename({ suffix: '.min' }),
            gulp.dest('public/assets/dist/css/')
        ],
        pumpCb
    );
});

gulp.task('prod-js', function (pumpCb) {
    return pump([
            gulp.src('public/assets/src/js/**/*.js'),
            uglify(),
            rename({ suffix: '.min' }),
            gulp.dest('public/assets/dist/js')
        ],
        pumpCb
    );
});

// Calls

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.watch('public/assets/src/sass/**/*.scss',['local-sass']);
    gulp.watch('public/assets/src/js/**/*.js',['local-js']);
});

gulp.task('prod', function () {
    runSequence('prod-sass','prod-css','prod-js');
});
```

From the documentation of `run-sequence` and `pump` I can't see what I'm doing wrong, so perhaps it's a wider misunderstanding of Gulp?

I've read most of the answers around the same error, but I don't think they apply to this specific case, nor could I see how to extrapolate their findings onto my own Gulpfile.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try removing `pumpCB` from each task's function parameter. I don't believe you can provide a callback to a task function AND return a stream.

Comment: Just tried it, and while it removes the callback issue, it also means that if my SASS has an error, node just reports `Error: premature close`, not a helpful error about what and where in the SASS something went wrong. Is there no right way to be using `pump`, `sequence` and callback errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got that error in my gulp task too. It's because you have a `return` statement AND you're calling the task callback `pumpCb`. Remove the `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks again, saw your comment on the GitHub issue too. Now just have to wrap my head around why, in my Gulpfile, the local-js task is running the rename function from prod-js - even though they're in different tasks..!

Comment: @RobertTolton, I see you never clear out your `dist/` directory. Maybe you're seeing `.min` files in there from a previous execution of your `prod` task?

Comment: Even if I clear out the `dist` folder manually, the `local-js` task still somehow creates a minified file.